# SQL - Show multiple values across different columns

Tags: sql, select

I have the following query, which is basically showing the number of messages being sent on a per user basis across a number of weeks.

There are a number of different messages types and I would like to see these results on one line per week as separate columns, but can't seem to work out the best way to achieve these results..

So I would like to end up with something like.

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6
Username,Week,TotalofMessage,TypeA,TypeB,TypeC
```

Currently I'm getting a separate row for each Username, Week, Type.. So for the 3 different types I have three ROWS.

```
SELECT 
   ui.display_name, to_char(msg.received_at,'yyyy IW'), 
   msg.message_type_id, count(msg.message_id) AS MESSAGES
FROM 
   message msg 
INNER JOIN 
   user_info ui ON ui.entity_id = msg.from_entity 
WHERE  
   msg.received_at > sysdate -30
   AND msg.from_entity = 2 
GROUP BY 
   ui.display_name, to_char(msg.received_at,'yyyy IW'), msg.message_type_id
ORDER BY 
   to_char(msg.received_at,'yyyy IW') DESC
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for what you want to do:

```
SELECT ui.display_name, to_char(msg.received_at, 'yyyy IW'), 
       count(msg.message_id) AS MESSAGES,
       sum(case when msg.message_type_id = A then 1 else 0 end) as messages_a,
       sum(case when msg.message_type_id = B then 1 else 0 end) as messages_b,
       sum(case when msg.message_type_id = C then 1 else 0 end) as messages_c
FROM message msg INNER JOIN 
     user_info ui
     ON ui.entity_id = msg.from_entity 
WHERE msg.received_at > sysdate -30 AND msg.from_entity = 2 
GROUP BY ui.display_name, to_char(msg.received_at,'yyyy IW')
ORDER BY to_char(msg.received_at,'yyyy IW') DESC;
```

Fill in `A`, `B`, and `C` with the appropriate values.  Note that I also removed the `message_type_id` from the `group by`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.. So for my benefit, CASE will evaluate the value of the message type and IF True, will SUM the results and the display the output as a new column.. I've learnt something new today..

Comment: @Boardman411 . . . Yes, you understand `case` correctly.  `case` is ANSI standard, so it is supported by almost all databases.